# How do married women whose professions are physically demanding cover their hair?

Tags: women, product-recommendation, tznius-modesty, hair, employment

I'm assuming that somewhere in the world there are observant married women who work as police officers, builders, and other physically demanding jobs where an ordinary scarf, hat, or wig may not stay on well.

What tends to be used as hair covering in those situations?

Comment: I'd like to point out that there are different opinions as to how hair should be covered... All of it, *heker*, etc.

Comment: @AviD, correct, that's a different question ...

Comment: In Israel they wear mostly snoods, or hair bags as I like to call them. (ok not really)

Answer (score 11):

I was a paramedic for a long time.  The one frum woman I knew who did this work wore a baseball cap with the EMS department LOGO on it as part of the "uniform".  In the winter she wore a winter hat with the same logo.

She had reletively short hair that all fit into the caps.

Comment: Eytan, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for sharing your experience! Please consider registering your account, so that the site can keep track of your contributions no matter which computer you log in from.